# how to get saved text into edit text

Tags: android

How could save the text as a text edit so that after leaving the activity and re-enter, It appear in the same edit text?

```
    switchbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Switch sw = (Switch) v;

            if (sw.isChecked()) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = settings.edit();
                editor1.putString("nombre", ed1.getText().toString());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = settings.edit();
                editor2.putString("apellido", ed2.getText().toString());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = settings.edit();
                editor3.putString("ciudad", ed3.getText().toString());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor4 = settings.edit();
                editor4.putString("calle", ed4.getText().toString());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor5 = settings.edit();
                editor5.putString("numero", ed5.getText().toString());
                editor1.commit();
                editor2.commit();
                editor3.commit();
                editor4.commit();
                editor5.commit();   
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(OtraActivity.this, "Datos no guardados",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }});
```

Comment: I'd advise reading the documentation on SharedPreferences, as you're already using it to store your data and loading your data isn't really much different: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreate`, `onStart`, or wherever you have loaded your views, you can load the data from prefs and insert it into your views:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
    ed1.setText(settings.getString("nombre", ""));
    ed2.setText(settings.getString("apellido", ""));
    ...
}
```

In `onPause`, you can save it just as you are when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

As cloudymusic suggested, use SharedPreferences, and your activity's `onPause()` store the data, and in the `onResume()` load it again, and you'll have your EditText's data persistent even when the App is closed

Answer (score 1):

Use the following onCreate

SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
                 ed1.setText(settings.getString("nombre",""));

do the same for the other edittext..